# IOS app failed to connect with sails.js server through socket.io(SIOSocket)

Tags: ios, socket.io, sails.js

I'm trying to build a  IOS application like MegaBits/WorldPin(https://github.com/MegaBits/WorldPin.git). The different is i used a sails on server.  I failed to connect with my server . 
in IOS client the code is :

[SIOSocket socketWithHost: @"http://localhost:1339" response: ^(SIOSocket *socket){

```
    self.socketIO = socket;
    socket.onConnect = ^()
    {
        NSLog(@"somebody onConnect");
        self.isConnected = YES;
    };
```

}

Did i missing something? how can i connect with a sails server in IOS using SIOSocket.

Answer (score 1):

Use your IP address instead of localhost.